# Is there a way in azure devops to get a report with all the test cases along with linked bugs and its severity?

Tags: azure, azure-devops

I am trying to create a query or a dashboard/report that gives me the test cases and its associated bugs that are linked to them along with severity.

Also is there a way to get the test case and along its execution status in a query or report?

Answer (score 1):

You can create [Query](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/queries/query-index-quick-ref?view=azure-devops)(type of `Work items and direct links`) in azure devops to query the test cases and its associated bugs. See below example: All the test cases that are associated to a bug whoes severity is smaller than 2 (ie. 1) will be queried. You can change the `Filter Options` to get a different result.

[image]

You can export the result to csv by clicking the `Export to CSV` option.

Please check document [Use direct links to view dependencies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/queries/using-queries?view=azure-devops#use-direct-links-to-view-dependencies) for more information.

As for getting test case and along its execution status. There is no query to query test case along its execution status.

You can view the test case and its execution status in the [Test Plans](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/test/?view=azure-devops) page. If the test cases are included in a test plan. You can view their outcome from their test plans in Test Plans section in ADO project port. You can aslo go to the `Runs` under Test Plans, select or enter the runId to view the test results of this test run.

You can also check out Rest Api to get the test results. See [Results - List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/test/results/list?view=azure-devops-rest-6.1).

See example [here](https://tenbulls.co.uk/2020/03/11/querying-azure-devops-rest-api-with-powershell/) to call rest api with powershell scripts. See [here](https://sanderh.dev/call-Azure-DevOps-REST-API-Postman/) to call rest api with postman.